# Show that $h_{\alpha}$ is independent of choice of non-degenerate bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I try to solve the following problem

> Show that $h_{\alpha}$ is independent of the choice of $(\, ,\, )$: replacing the
>   Killing form by any other non-degenerate symmetric invariant bilinear form gives the same $h_{\alpha}$ .
>
> Here $h_{\alpha}$ is defined by
>   $$h_{\alpha}=\frac{H_{\alpha}}{(H_{\alpha},H_{\alpha})}$$
>   where $\alpha$ is a root and $H_{\alpha}$ is the corresponding element in $\mathfrak{h}$ under the isomorphism $\mathfrak{h}\xrightarrow{\sim}\mathfrak{h}^*$ induced by $(\, ,\,)$.
>
> Hint: show it first for a simple Lie algebra, then use Theorem:
>
> Let $\mathfrak{g}_1, \cdots, \mathfrak{g}_n$ be simple Lie algebras and let 
>   $$\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus \mathfrak{g}_i$$ 
>   Let $\mathfrak{h}_i\subset \mathfrak{g}_i$ be Cartan subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}_i$ and $R_i \subset \mathfrak{h}^*$ the corresponding root systems of $\mathfrak{g}_i$. Then $$\mathfrak{h}=\bigoplus\mathfrak{h}_i$$
>   is a Cartan subalgebra in $\mathfrak{g}$ and the corresponding root system is
>   $$R=\coprod R_i.$$

---

I proved this for simple case. And I got stuck when I generalized the result to semisimple case. How to apply that theorem?

All what I know it every semisimple Lie algebra can be decomposed to simple Lie algebra. So what?

Any hint or answer are welcomed! Thank you.

Comment: I solved it. I will post my answer if anyone wants to know.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know the solution. Would you mind posting it here?